# Index out of Range issue in with python split function

Tags: python, split

What's wrong with this piece of code?

## --ipfile is an ip text file

```
ipfile= open(filename,'rU')
for line in ipfile:
 list_words = line.split()
 fwrd= list_words[0]
```

I like to check first word and if it is an integer I like to do something else. Why does the fwrd assignment give me index of of range error?

EDIT:Added the file opening line. Also note that if I print `list_words`  I can see all the lines from the file printed for e.g:

```
['45', 'PAN', 'RECTANGULAR', 'STAINLESS,', '350X270X63MM', '172123', '2.00', 'PCS']
['Details', ':', 'Stainless', 'steel', 'made', 'pan', 'for', 'storing', 'meat,', 'fish,', 'vegetables,', 'etc.', 'prior', 'to', 'cooking.']
```

Comment: May be your ipfile is empty or there is no space in line. Please give the full code and data of `ipfile`.

Comment: Check the length of split using `len(list_words)`, it should be zero if the error comes up.

Comment: print list_words before accessing you will get to know  the reason for error

Comment: ...`for line in [ipfile]:`...

Comment: Updated my question; I see the file content when I print list_words

Answer (score 3):

The `split` method always returns a list with at least one element unless the input is empty string (`''`).
change your code to:

```
for line in ipfile.readlines():
    if line != '\n':
        list_words = line.split()
        fwrd= list_words[0] 
        # the do whaever you want with fwrd
```

Comment: Not sure how to update the question with more code...but to your point if I print list_words it prints all the  lines for eg...['This', 'is', 'a', 'System', 'Generated', 'Purchase', 'Order', 'and', 'does', 'not', 'require', 'signature.'] . I'm opening the file with  ipfile= open(filename,'rU')

Comment: Thank you I think I got the idea, will update the code accordingly